# Can I modify the plug of my new bath fan to fit the non-polarized receptacle?

Tags: bathroom, fans

Can I file down the polarized plug of my replacement Pro Endurance bathroom fan to fit the existing female receptacle?

Comment: Can you? Sure. Is it a good idea? Not even a little bit.

Comment: Your receptacle is *THAT OLD*?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Hard to believe there are still houses built before 1970, huh?   Now get offa my lawn you young punk.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- no, more like built before polarized receptacles were a thing -- that easily makes his receptacles older than WWII.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  well,  http://www.mcgarryandmadsen.com/inspection/Blog/Entries/2016/4/20_Why_are_electrical_outlets_and_plugs_polarized.html  says the earliest NEC code they could find which mentions polarized sockets was 1962.  I certainly bought equipment (new)  in the 70s which did not have polarized plugs .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- non-polarized plugs are still a thing because Class II (double insulated) devices don't give a hoot about which way hot and neutral go.

Comment: Nonpolarized ***plugs***, yes Nonpolarized **sockets**, no.

Comment: Additional info:  The female receptacle is hard-wired into the ceiling (1973).  I don't want to tear the ceiling out just to change the receptacle.  That's why I wanted to file down the male prong of the new fan plug.  New fan is identical to the old fan except for the plug.

Answer (score 4):

No, no, no!  It's polarized for a reason.

Just replace the receptacle with a **polarized** receptacle.  Make sure the taller slot is on the neutral side.

They look like this, note the absence of a ground pin.  There may be a green screw on the outlet nonetheless, that grounds the outlet.  It should be left disconnected unless ground is actually present in the box.  This is a current product legally sold all over in [white](http://amzn.to/29rsXjM), [ivory](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-2-Wire-Duplex-Outlet-Ivory-R51-00223-00I/100356968) or [brown](http://www.lowes.com/pd/Cooper-Wiring-Devices-15-Amp-125-Volt-Brown-Duplex-Electrical-Outlet/3569026).

[image]

As a footnote, this is a **polarized** receptacle.  The other type, with 3 slots, is a **grounded** receptacle. If you really need one of those, there's a legal way to do that using GFCI's.  As such there is never a reason to break off a ground pin.

Comment: Ummm.. no,  you can't "just replace" the receptacle unless the wiring supports ground as well as neutral.  It's clear the OP is not familiar with electricity in general, and is unlikely to identify hot vs neutral in the first place, so advising him to DIY may lead to a dangerous situation.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- no, there are Code provisions in 406.4(D)(2) supporting the replacement of an ungrounded receptacle with another ungrounded receptacle, or with a GFCI if a safety upgrade is desired without running new wires.

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify any misunderstanding about what a polarized outlet is. @CarlWitthoft   It seems weirdly imperious to try to judge a poster's skills based on a single sentence they wrote, moreso, an answer for presuming competence.  This is a DIY forum and our job is to give right answers.  As discussed elsewhere, "Hire a professional" answers are not desired unless a case can be made for why.   http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/hire-a-professional-answers

Comment: @Harper  Maybe, but I get very nervous when people start suggesting filing down a pin.  That is not anything I'd expect to hear from anyone who knows enough about electrical wiring to safely rewire things.  Yes, it's DIY,  but that doesn't mean we should let people free-run w/o warnings.